# Video.attachCamera(null) doesn't work

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash

There's this weird thing that when I try to execute the swf file independently, it can attach the camera then remove it and makes the video freeze (well that's the desired result)

but

when I tried to embed it into an html then deployed in a local server, when I am dettaching the camera via `video.attachCamera(null)` it doesn't work and the camera is still there and I can still see myself moving.

Why? and How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fount the issue. It's because of the framework I used. It's robotlegs MVC maybe there's something wrong with my code or it's a bug of the framework itself. Changed my code not to use robotlegs.